# Avoiding for loops while subsetting and plotting in r

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, ggplot2, dplyr

What is the best way to avoid the for-loops used below? They loop over the "states", using them to subset the data for plotting and label the title. Maybe an `apply` function is suitable with a user defined function, but I'm not sure what that would be such that it also avoids for-loops.

```
# Attach packages
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)

# Create data
set.seed(123)
states <- c("s1","s2","s3")
d <- data.frame(Year = sample(2010:2016, 1000, replace=T), 
           Month = sample(1:12, 1000, replace=T), 
           DepartureState = sample(states, 1000, replace=T), 
           DestinationState = sample(states, 1000, replace=T), 
           Price = sample(5000:8000, 1000, replace=T), 
           Cost = sample(2000:3000, 1000, replace=T))

# Apply grouping
dg <- d %>%
  group_by( Year, Month, DepState = DepartureState, DestState = DestinationState ) %>% 
  summarise( sumPrice = sum(Price), sumCost = sum(Cost), diff = sumPrice-sumCost, vol = n() )

# Add date column
dg$date <- as.POSIXct(paste(dg$Year, dg$Month, "01", sep = "-"))      

# Do things, e.g. subset and plot, for each combination of DepState-DestState pairs
for ( depState in states ) { 
  for ( destState in states ) {
    dgcut <- dg[dg$DepState == depState & dg$DestState == destState, ]

    description <- paste0(depState," to ", destState)
    plotname <- paste0(depState,"_",destState)
    #png(filename=paste0(plotname,".png"))
    p1 <- ggplot(dgcut, aes(x=date, y=sumPrice)) + geom_line() 
    p2 <- ggplot(dgcut, aes(x=date, y=sumCost)) + geom_line()
    p3 <- ggplot(dgcut, aes(x=date, y=diff)) + geom_line()
    p4 <- ggplot(dgcut, aes(x=date, y=vol)) + geom_line()
    grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,ncol=1,top = description) # from gridExtra
    #dev.off()
  }
}
```

Note, I am only trying to avoid for-loops because I understand it is considered bad practice (or sub-optimal) in a vectorised language like R. If that is not true for this case, please let me  know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaining `lapply` instead of `for` loops?

```
doThings <- function(depState,destState) {
    dgcut <- dg[dg$DepState == depState & dg$DestState == destState, ]

    description <- paste0(depState," to ", destState)
    plotname <- paste0(depState,"_",destState)
    #png(filename=paste0(plotname,".png"))
    p1 <- ggplot(dgcut, aes(x=date, y=sumPrice)) + geom_line() 
    p2 <- ggplot(dgcut, aes(x=date, y=sumCost)) + geom_line()
    p3 <- ggplot(dgcut, aes(x=date, y=diff)) + geom_line()
    p4 <- ggplot(dgcut, aes(x=date, y=vol)) + geom_line()
    grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,ncol=1,top = description) # from gridExtra
    #dev.off()
}

lapply(states,function(x) lapply(states,doThings,destState = x))
```

Comment: Cool, I hadn't thought of nesting an `apply` like that. Thanks @shreyasgm!

Comment: Using `l_ply` (package plyr) instead of `lapply` will speed up the process further.